# Изменение данных в одной таблице по запросу в другую

Tags: sql, ms-access

Есть access 2007. Есть таблица "Книги" и "Книги_в_залах". Есть форма, добавляющая новую книгу в первую таблицу. В форме есть все нужные параметры (шифр, номер зала и количество) для создания записи и во второй таблице. Собственно, как это сделать?

Comment: *форма, добавляющая новую книгу в первую таблицу.* Надеюсь, добавление выполняется по нажатию кнопки на форме? А то с триггерами в 2007 - совсем тухло. Нету их...

Comment: Есть отдельная для добавления, и ещё всё, что записано и корректно, добавляется при закрытии формы.

Comment: *всё, что записано и корректно, добавляется при закрытии формы* То есть в Form_Close или в Form_Unload? ну так кто мешает заодно и во вторую таблицу записать, ещё одним запросом?